# on what matters does the ICJ have compulsory jurisdiction?

Tags: treaty

in the ICJ statute it is stated

> The jurisdiction of the Court comprises all cases which the parties refer to it and all matters specially provided for in the Charter of the United Nations or in treaties and conventions in force.

does this mean ICJ have compulsory jurisdiction on matters related to UN charter ?

Answer (score 2):

The scope of compulsory jurisdiction at the ICJ is by unilateral declaration of each nation. You can see the declarations of states that have assented to compulsory jurisdiction of the ICJ here: https://www.icj-cij.org/en/declarations

Each declaration specifies the scope of compulsory jurisdiction that the state is assenting to.

For example, Romania has said it does not accept compulsory jurisdiction for "any dispute regarding to the protection of the environment."

I believe all the states that have conditioned their acceptance of compulsory jurisdiction on the opposing state having accepted the same obligation. E.g. Sweden

> accepts as compulsory ipso facto and without special agreement, **in relation to any other State accepting the same obligation**, the jurisdiction of the International Court of Justice, ...